# Select only documents with a certain response (Lotus Notes)

Tags: select, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

In lotus notes, I have documents which can have many types (Forms) of response documents.

I would like to select documents that have a certain response document with them.

For example:

```
Doc1
--Response1 (Red)
--Response2 (Blue)
Doc2
--Response1(Red)
Doc3
--Response1(Blue)
--Response2(Green)
```

If I would like 'all documents with a response of form type 'blue'' (eg Doc1 & Doc 3), how would I do that? It seems like I can only base criteria off of the main document.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to select them. Note that response documents all contain a reference to their parent document in the $REF field.

**In a view:** If you want them to appear in a view only if they have a certain type of response document, they need to have a field value that indicates they have that kind of response. So, when someone saves the response document, have it also change a field on the parent document to indicate that it has that kind of response.

**In an agent:** Instead of looking at the parent documents, cycle through the response documents of the type you want and return information about or from the parent document.

Comment: Since I do want the parents as well, I assumed I need a field like that. I am enacting a retroactive change, so I guess that means an agent to enact it retroactively as well. Crap. haha. Well, thank you!